# Display the object names and types from the USER_OBJECTS data dictionary view EMPLOYEE and DEPARTMENT tables

Tags: sqlplus, where-clause

I'm having trouble with the where clause...

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE
FROM USER_OBJECTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('EMPLOYEE', 'DEPARTMENT');
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out -

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type
FROM user_constraints 
WHERE table_name IN ('EMPLOYEE', 'DEPARTMENT');
```